# create a python shell environment launcher to use pyQgis

Tags: python, shell, windows-xp, cmd, qgis

I am trying to modify the shell launcher found at "http://inasafe.linfiniti.com/html/id/developer-docs/platform_windows.html" so that I can use it to directly launch any shell I'd like (in my case, I wanna use the default IDLE gui in Python 27 library folder for windows).
My changes didn't bring me to an acceptable result so far. Here is my version of the launcher, where I should change it?

```
@echo off
SET PyShell=C:\Programmi\Quantum GIS Lisboa
call "%PyShell%"\apps\Python27\Lib\idlelib\PyShell.pyc
@echo off
SET GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=%PyShell%\bin\gdalplugins\1.9
path %PATH%;%PyShell%\apps\qgis\bin
path %PATH%;%PyShell%\apps\grass\grass-6.4.2\lib
path %PATH%;"%PyShell%\apps\Python27\Scripts\"

set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%PyShell%\apps\qgis\python;
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%PyShell%\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%PyShell%\apps\qgis

start "Quantum GIS Shell" /B "cmd.exe" %*
```

My OS is Windows XP, the version of Python is 2.7.3, while Qgis is 1.8 (Lisboa).
I am reeeeally new to Python and stuff, so please forgive my big mistakes if there are some (but I'm pretty sure there are).

Comment: What kind of results are you getting? What error messages, if any?

Comment: Firstly I get this error message from the prompt "Traceback <most recent call last>: File "<string>", line 1, in <module> ImportError: No module named run". Then the IDLE gui opens, but a window named "Subprocess Startup Error" shows up readings "IDLE's subprocess didn't make connection. Either IDLE can't start a subprocess or personal firewall software is blocking the connection". I am now cotrolling my firewall settings.

Comment: It wasn't the firewall...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the solution was int the line where I specify which program to use as shell. In my case, I found bot "Pyshell.pyc" and "idle.pyw". The second seems to be the right to poit at, as everything works fine now.
So, my personal shell launcher looks like this:

```
@echo off
SET IDLE=C:\PROGRA~1\QUANTU~1
call "%IDLE%"\apps\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw
@echo off
SET GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=%IDLE%\bin\gdalplugins\1.9
path %PATH%;%IDLE%\apps\qgis\bin
path %PATH%;%IDLE%\apps\grass\grass-6.4.2\lib
path %PATH%;"%IDLE%\apps\Python27\Scripts\"

set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%IDLE%\apps\qgis\python;
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%IDLE%\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%IDLE%\apps\qgis

start "Quantum GIS Shell" /B "cmd.exe" %*
```

Anyway, this was a workaround to set the environment variables to use PyQGIS, as I had difficulties to set them in the "normal" way.
Unfortuntely, I didn't fix my problem, as I'm still getting errors while importing the "qgis.core" module, while using the original shell launcher through cmd.exe it works, but it's not a good IDE though...